# hive sql join statment

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a query

```
with ex as (
select z.num number, car.id as id, car.make as make, car.model, 'vehicles' as type from mytable mt LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(mt.vehicles) vehiclestbl as honda
where car.working = true
union all
select z.num number, plane.id as id, plane.make as make, plane.model, 'flights' as type from mytable mt LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(mt.flights) flightstbl as wings
where plane.active = true
union all
select z.num number, train.id as id, train.make as make, train.model, 'departures' as type from mytable mt LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(mt.departures) departurestbl as wheels
where wheels.active = true
)

select ex0.*, 1499 as cost, model as location
from ex ex0
where mycolumn = 15
```

The end results looks something like this

```
number    id      make     model    type    cost      location
323       abc     make1    model1   type1   1499      modelLoc1
329       xyz     make2    model2   type2   1499      modelLoc2
984       lks     make3    model3   type3   1499      modelLoc3
```

I am trying to join a column 'number' with another outside table. When ever i add a

```
INNER JOIN myothertable mot on mot.id = ex_id;
```

I get an 'cannot recognize input near' Error

Answer (score 0):

In the CTE, the column is called `number` so I would expect the query to look like to look like:

```
select ex0.*, 1499 as cost, model as location
from ex ex0 inner join
     myothertable mot
     on mot.id = ex0.number;
where mycolumn = 15;
```

Comment: i get an error Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Column title Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries

Comment: `title` is not referred to in this query at all, so I don't see how it could cause that error.  But you can fix this error by qualifying the table names (i.e. including the table alias).